# Most different openings by transpositions?

Tags: opening, defense, transpositions

What sequence of opening moves can include most different named Openings or Defenses by transpositions?

For example, I just played a bullet game that went:

1.d4 e5 2. e4 d6 3. Nf3 Nc6 4. Bb5.

In this sequence, we have, in just four moves:

Queen’s Pawn Opening;
Englund Gambit;
King’s Pawn Opening;
Center Game;
Philidor’s Defense;
Ruy Lopez;
Steinitz Defense to the Ruy Lopez;

Very interesting is also:

1.e4 d5 2.d4 c6 (or 2...e6), and so on.

Are there any other similar (or better) examples of this kind?

Comment: Sure, but the number of moves increases. One could always go 1.Nf3 and 2.Ng1 to have the Reti included, for example.

Comment: Take a look at Panov-attack Caro-Kann's that magically enter Queen's gambit territory

Comment: I've had more than one game go pirc/modern -> kings indian -> benoni -> benko

Comment: I'm not sure of the names of all the openings but I think this one went through a few transpositions: 1.d4 Nc6 2.e4 e5 3.Nf3 exd4 4.Nxd4 Nf6 5.Nc3 Nxe4. Queen's Pawn Game, Bogoljubow Defense, Nimzovitch Defense, Kevitz Defense, Scotch Game, Scotch Four Knights Game.

Answer (score 2):

Another well-known example is the following:

```
[fen ""] 
1. f4 {Bird's Opening} 1... e5 {From Gambit} 2. e4 {King's Gambit} 2... d5 {Falkbeer Counter Gambit} 3. exd5 exf4 {King's Gambit Accepted}
```

A total of 5 distinct names.
Bird's Opening
From Gambit
King's Gambit
Falkbeer Counter Gambit
King's Gambit Accepted

Comment: Shouldn't that last one be Falkbeer Countergambit Accepted, not King's Gambit Accepted? King's Gambit Accepted would involve exf4.

Comment: @dm The last move is exf4. That's where it transposes. 3... e4 or 3... c6 are the main lines of the Falkbeer.

Comment: OK, I have no idea how I missed the last move.